# How do I get an answer of $14$ using simpsons rule for $\frac{152e}{180n^4}<.0001$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, simpsons-rule

I must have the algebra wrong somewhere but here is the original equation:

$$\frac{152e}{180n^4}<.0001$$

If I then multiply like this:

$$152e<.0001(180)n^4$$

Which then gives:

$$152e < .0018n^4$$

And then dividing:

$$\frac{152e}{.0018} < n^4$$

And then taking the fourth root:

$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{152e}{.0018}}< \sqrt[4]{n^4}$$

And I get about $n = 46.338$

But the book gives a solution of $14$.  Can someone explain where I went wrong?

Comment: I'm getting $22$ as my answer.  Is it possible that you are missing parenthesis, e.g. $(180 \cdot n )^4$?  Not that this would give the right answer, but I feel like you might be missing something.

Comment: @Ryan hmm... that's possible.  But still not sure where the 14 comes from.

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency between the first and second lines, by the way.  Is it $0.00001$, or $0.0001$?

Comment: @Ryan, good catch, there should be $3$ zeros and then a $1$ making $.0001$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{152 \mathrm{e}}{180n^4}<0.0001$

$152 \mathrm{e} < 0.018n^4$

$\dfrac{152 \mathrm{e} }{0.018} < n^4$

$n > \sqrt[4]{22954.38}$

$n > 12.31$

This still doesn't explain why the solution is listed as $14$, though.

Comment: Ryan, thanks!  This is the answer I got as well.  I just going to assume the system is generating the wrong answer (it's a homework system) because every random problem has a solution of 14.